# SharePoint: Edit an issue and get greyed out fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, edit-form, issue-tracking

I created in SharePoint online an Issue library. The Enduser will fill out the form. But if the Enduser want to add an comment he has to edit the issue. In this edit-form I want greyed out all other field. Is this possible?

Comment: One more way is to use Client Side Rendering. Refer this link for the reference - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Sample-8-List-add-and-edit-d228b751

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps if you are using OOTB edit form, else you can still use the script, but you need to modify the selectors.

1. Open the Issue Tracking Edit form.
2. From Gear Icon, click on Edit Page.
3. Add a Script Editor Web part to the page. (From Group select Media and Content).
4. Put the below script in script editor form.

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function disableColumns(){
        $('input, select, textarea', '.ms-formbody').prop('disable', true).css('background-color', '#ccc');
        $('textarea[title="Comments"', '.ms-formbody').removeProp('disable').css('background-color', '#ccc');

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        disableColumns();
    })
</script>
```

Thats it. You are done here. When user will edit form it will like like this.

[image]